# Stationarity of time series when there is a clear trend

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

Hi I'm new to time series analysis and analyzing mobility level time series these days. The mobility level time series show a clear trend (increasing over time); however when I run Augmented Dickey Fuller test to see if the time series object (without de-trend or de-seasonality) is stationary, it gives me a p-value of <0.01, indicating it is stationary. Is this possible?

Also, I'm using R studio to analyze the time series object. When I run adf.test, it gives me a result like below:

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  mobility.ts
Dickey-Fuller = -4.8819, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

However, after I import `aTSA` (Alternative Time Series Analysis) package, it gives me the result :

```
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test 
alternative: stationary 
 
Type 1: no drift no trend 
     lag    ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -1.464   0.153
[2,]   1 -1.019   0.313
[3,]   2 -0.193   0.587
[4,]   3  0.113   0.675
Type 2: with drift no trend 
     lag   ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -3.32  0.0183
[2,]   1 -2.60  0.0992
[3,]   2 -1.45  0.5367
[4,]   3 -1.21  0.6240
Type 3: with drift and trend 
     lag   ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -4.35  0.0100
[2,]   1 -3.71  0.0273
[3,]   2 -2.40  0.4080
[4,]   3 -2.06  0.5479
----
```

I am a bit confused why the p-values are different and why the first case rejects the null hypothesis and the second case doesn't.

Comment: In doing Augmented Dickey-Fuller test, the lag intended to be tested can be specified. The difference between specifying lags can be found at the top subsections of [this](https://nwfsc-timeseries.github.io/atsa-labs/sec-boxjenkins-aug-dickey-fuller.html) part of book.

Comment: ADF have low power and thus may not reject a null when they should. Also a trend can be deterministic rather than stochastic - I don't know if ADF captures that.